# General Solution to PDE after transformation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the PDE for $v(x,y)$:

> $v_{xx} − v_{xy} − 6v_{yy} − 5v_{x} − 10v_{y} + 25 = 0$

Taking $\xi = y-2x$ and $\eta=y+3x$ that I found from $b^2-4ac$ I have transformed the equation to the form

$v_{\eta\xi} + v_{\eta}=1$

I have been posed the question:

> Using this result obtain the general solution, casting your answer in terms of
>   the x and y variables.

I am not sure how to solve this problem. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Yes! I edited, thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: Did you get a solution $v(\eta, \xi)$?  What was it?

Comment: This is as much as I have gotten, I found the characteristic curves and used them to reduce the pde to canonical form, I haven't got anywhere else. If I am missing something fundamental, please point it out, I am trying to grasp this process as best I can!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we have :
$$v_{\eta\xi} + v_{\eta}=1$$
Now let $u=v_{\eta} $
$$ u=v_{\eta} \Rightarrow u_{\xi}=v_{\eta\xi}$$
$$\Rightarrow u_{\xi}+u = 1$$
$$\frac{-d_{\xi}}{1}=\frac{-d_{\eta}}{0}=\frac{du}{u-1}$$
which implies :
$$\eta=a \ , \ u-1=be^-{\xi}\Rightarrow u=1+f(\eta)e^-{\xi}$$
Finally :
$$v_{\eta}=1+f(\xi)e^-{\xi}\Rightarrow v=\eta +\int_{\eta}f(s)e^-{\xi}ds+g(\xi) $$
$$ v=\eta+e^-\xi \int_{\eta}f(s)ds+g(\xi) $$
$$ v=\eta +h(\eta)e^-\xi +g(\xi) $$
$$v=x+3y+h(x+3y)e^{-(x-2y)}+g(x-2y)$$

Comment: What is the step after ⇒ $u_{ξ}+u=1$ if you don't mind me asking, what is it you did?

Comment: This is the subsidiary equation for Lagrange’s first-order linear partial DE.

Comment: I have just edited the post .

Answer (score 0):

Solve PDE
$$v_{xx} − v_{xy} − 6v_{yy} − 5v_{x} − 10v_{y} + 25 = 0 $$

- $D_x^2-D_xD_y-6D_y^2-5D_x-10D_y=
  \left( {D_x}-3 {D_y}-5\right) \, \left( {D_x}+2 {D_y}\right)$
- General solution of $\quad v_x+2v_y=0\quad$ is $\quad v_1=f(y-2x)$
- General solution of $\quad v_x-3v_y-5v= 0\quad$ is $\quad v_2=e^{5x}g(3x+y)$
- Partial solution of PDE is $\quad v_p=5x$
- General solution of PDE is $v=v_1+v_2+v_p=f(y-2x)+e^{5x}g(3x+y)+5x$