How to find the second canonical form of a given hyperbolic equation?
Consider the equation $$ y^2 u_{xx} - x^2 u_{yy} = 0. $$
The method used to solve this problem is given below(, and for the real solution given in the book please scroll down):




The solution given in the book is as follows:
Here $$ A = y^2, \quad B = 0, \quad C = -x^2. $$ Thus, $$ B^2 - 4AC = 4x^2 y^2 > 0. $$ The equation is hyperbolic everywhere except on the coordinate axes (x = 0) and (y = 0). From the characteristic equations (4.2.5) and (4.2.6), we have $$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x}{y}, \quad \frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{x}{y}. $$ After integration of these equations, we obtain $$ x^2 - y^2 = c_1, \quad x^2 + y^2 = c_2. $$ The first of these curves is a family of hyperbolas $$ \frac{1}{2}y^2 - \frac{1}{2}x^2 = c_1, $$ and the second is a family of circles $$ \frac{1}{2}y^2 + \frac{1}{2}x^2 = c_2. $$ To transform the given equation to canonical form, we consider $$ \xi = \frac{1}{2} y^2 - \frac{1}{2} x^2, \quad \eta = \frac{1}{2} y^2 + \frac{1}{2} x^2. $$ From the relations (4.1.6), we have \begin{align*} u_x &= u_\xi \xi_x + u_\eta \eta_x = -x u_\xi + x u_\eta, \ u_y &= u_\xi \xi_y + u_\eta \eta_y = y u_\xi + y u_\eta, \ u_{xx} &= u_{\xi \xi} \xi_x^2 + 2 u_{\xi \eta} \xi_x \eta_x + u_{\eta \eta} \eta_x^2 + u_\xi \xi_{xx} + u_\eta \eta_{xx} = x^2 u_{\xi \xi} - 2x^2 u_{\xi \eta} + x^2 u_{\eta \eta} + u_\xi + u_\eta, \ u_{yy} &= u_{\xi \xi} \xi_y^2 + 2 u_{\xi \eta} \xi_y \eta_y + u_{\eta \eta} \eta_y^2 + u_\xi \xi_{yy} + u_\eta \eta_{yy} = y^2 u_{\xi \xi} + 2y^2 u_{\xi \eta} + y^2 u_{\eta \eta} + u_\xi + u_\eta. \end{align*} Thus, the given equation assumes the canonical form $$ u_{\xi \eta} = \frac{2(\xi^2 - \eta^2) u_\xi - 2(\xi^2 - \eta^2) u_\eta}{4}. $$

However, in terms of the method I attached previously, it seems that it's only the first canonical form. In the last paragraph pf the described method, it's written,

Now if new independent variables $$ \alpha = \xi + \eta, \quad \beta = \xi - \eta, $$ are introduced, then equation (4.2.7) is transformed into $$ u_{\alpha \alpha} - u_{\beta \beta} = H_2(\alpha, \beta, u, u_\alpha, u_\beta). $$ This form is called the second canonical form of the hyperbolic equation.

But I don't get how to transform $(4.2.7)$ to the form $$ u_{\alpha \alpha} - u_{\beta \beta} = H_2(\alpha, \beta, u, u_\alpha, u_\beta). $$ This is the reason why I am unable to find the second canonical form of the given hyperbolic equation. The rest part seems fine to me.
Any help regarding this apparent issue will be highly appreciated.
Please note that I know that the use of images are discouraged in this site, but typing all the stuffs in the images i attached seems very tiring and I think, in this case, it's better to post the images so as to distinguish it from the real solution of the problem. It would be very much valid to say that those images are simply used for the purposes of references.

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1546800/solving-y2u-xx-x2u-yy-0?noredirect=1

Let's first correct your result for the first canonical form. Using your results for $u_{xx}$ and $u_{yy}$, we get
\begin{align}
0&=y^2u_{xx}-x^2u_{yy} \\
&=y^2[x^2 (u_{\xi \xi} - 2u_{\xi \eta} + u_{\eta \eta}) - u_\xi + u_\eta] 
- x^2[y^2 (u_{\xi \xi} + 2 u_{\xi \eta} + u_{\eta \eta}) + u_\xi + u_\eta] \\
&=-4x^2y^2u_{\xi\eta}-(y^2+x^2)u_{\xi}+(y^2-x^2)u_{\eta} \\
&=4(\xi^2-\eta^2)u_{\xi\eta}-2\eta u_{\xi}+2\xi u_{\eta}, \tag{1}
\end{align}
hence
$$
u_{\xi\eta}=\frac{\eta u_{\xi}-\xi u_{\eta}}{2(\xi^2-\eta^2)}. \tag{2}
$$
To obtain the second canonical form, let's make the change of variables suggested by the textbook, $\alpha=\xi+\eta$ and $\beta=\xi-\eta$. Then
\begin{align}
u_{\xi}&=u_{\alpha}\alpha_{\xi}+u_{\beta}\beta_{\xi}=u_{\alpha}+u_{\beta}, \tag{3} \\
u_{\eta}&=u_{\alpha}\alpha_{\eta}+u_{\beta}\beta_{\eta}=u_{\alpha}-u_{\beta},  \tag{4} \\
u_{\xi\eta}&=(u_{\alpha}+u_{\beta})_{\alpha}\alpha_{\eta}+(u_{\alpha}+u_{\beta})_{\beta}\beta_{\eta}=u_{\alpha\alpha}+u_{\alpha\beta}-(u_{\beta\alpha}+u_{\beta\beta}) \\
&=u_{\alpha\alpha}-u_{\beta\beta}, \tag{5} \\
\xi&=\frac{\alpha + \beta}{2}, \tag{6} \\
\eta&=\frac{\alpha - \beta}{2}, \tag{7} \\
\xi^2-\eta^2&=(\xi+\eta)(\xi-\eta)=\alpha\beta. \tag{8}
\end{align}
Substituting $(3)$-$(8)$ in $(2)$, we finally obtain
$$
u_{\alpha\alpha}-u_{\beta\beta}=\frac{(\alpha-\beta)(u_{\alpha}+u_{\beta})-(\alpha+\beta)(u_{\alpha}-u_{\beta})}{4\alpha\beta}=\frac{u_{\beta}}{2\beta}-\frac{u_{\alpha}}{2\alpha}. \tag{9}
$$

Alternatively, one can rewrite the original PDE
$$
y^2u_{xx}-x^2u_{yy}=0 \tag{10}
$$
in the second canonical form using a single change of variables. First, let's rewrite $(10)$ as
$$
\frac{u_{xx}}{x^2}-\frac{u_{yy}}{y^2}=0. \tag{11}
$$
This suggests us to write $u(x,y)=v(s,t)$, where $s=s(x)$ and $t=t(y)$. Then
$$
u_x=v_ss'(x)\qquad\text{and}\qquad 
u_{xx}=v_{ss}[s'(x)]^2+v_ss''(x), \tag{12}
$$
with analogous expressions for $u_y$ and $u_{yy}$. Thus, Eq. $(11)$ becomes
$$
\frac{[s'(x)]^2}{x^2}\,v_{ss}-\frac{[t'(y)]^2}{y^2}\,v_{tt}
+\frac{s''(x)}{x^2}\,v_s-\frac{t''(y)}{y^2}\,v_t=0. \tag{13}
$$
Choosing $s(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}$ and $t(y)=\frac{y^2}{2}$, we simplify Eq. $(13)$ to
$$
v_{ss}-v_{tt}+\frac{v_s}{2s}-\frac{v_t}{2t}=0, \tag{14}
$$
which is equivalent to Eq. $(9)$.

By  $$u=x+y,\quad v=x-y$$
we have
$$\partial_x \ = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \partial_u \ + \ \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} \partial_v  = \ \partial_u + \partial_v $$
etc.
$$\partial_x^2 - \partial_y^2 =(\partial_x - \partial_y)(\partial_x + \partial_y) =\partial_{x+y}  \partial_{x-y}$$
It follows that in dimension 2 the wave equation has an indefinite quadratic form or a second order mixed form.
For higher  dimensions the mixed forms don't play any role, so called light cone coordinates are complex .eg. in dimension 4
$$\partial_t^2 - \Delta = \partial_{t+x}\partial_{t-x} - \partial_{y+ i z} \partial_{y-z}.$$
